# python lxml loop on match get next entry

Tags: python, list, lxml

I'm using LXML to query multiple XML files containing data elements on various products.  This section of code is taking a list of missing product_ids and querying the XML files for the data elements for the products.

One of my core issues is that every *product_id* obtained through xpath is checked against every item in the list *products_missing_from_postgresql*, which takes forever (hours)

How do I restart the *for entry in entries* loop when a match is found?

Maybe this isn't the right question...if not what is the right question?

```
# this code is for testing purposes 
for product_number in products_missing_from_postgresql:
try:
    for entry in entries:

       product_id = entry.xpath('@id')[0]

        if product_id != product_number:

            print('************************')
            print('current product: ' + product_id)
            print('no match: ' + product_number)
            print('************************')

        else:

            print('************************')
            print('************************')
            print('product to match: ' + product_number)
            print('matched from entry: ' + product_id)
            print('************************')
            print('************************')
```

Testing Code output:

```
************************
************************
product to match: B3F2H-STH 
matched from entry: B3F2H-STH 
************************
************************

************************
current product: B3F2H-STL
no match: B3F2H-STH 
************************

************************
current product: B3F2H-004 
no match: B3F2H-STH 
************************
```

This code is for production:

```
for product_number in products_missing_from_postgresql:

try:
for entry in entries:

    product_id = entry.xpath('@id')[0]

    if product_id != product_number:

        # used for testing
        print('no match: ' + product_number)

    else:
       # the element @id has multiple items linked that I need to acquire. 

       product_id = entry.xpath('@id')[0]
       missing_products_to_add.append(product_id)

       product_name = entry.xpath('@name')[0]
       missing_products_to_add.append(product_name)

       product_type = entry.xpath('@type')[0]
       missing_products_to_add.append(product_type)

       product_price = entry.xpath('@price')[0]
       missing_products_to_add.append(product_price)
```

Comment: If you write the inner loop as a function, you'll be able to return when you've found a match. This could also make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your IDs into a `set` and compare against that once - this'll save the nested loop and only does the XPaths once instead of keeping re-querying the tree...

```
ids = {pid for entry in entries for pid in entry.xpath('@id')}
for product_number in products_missing_from_postgresql:
    if product_number in ids:
        # whatever
    else:
        # whatever
```

If you want to also retrieve the elements then you can build a dictionary instead of a set:

```
products = {p.attrib['id']: p for entry in entries for p in entry.xpath('//*[@id]')}
for product_number in products_missing_from_postgresql:
    if product_number in products:
        actual_product = products[product_number]
        # ...
    else:
        # ...
```

Comment: Your code example worked, but how do call all the entry.xpath items when a match is found?   Before I was calling  product_id = entry.xpath('@id')[0]  to obtain the product_id, but now that doesn't work.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex sorry - I'm not quite understanding you - can you try rephrasing please?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I've added an example of building a dictionary instead of a set... I believe that's what you're after?

Comment: I felt that I needed to clarity my original post, so I added some items.  Thanks for helping me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an inner `for` loop, use XPath.

```
for product_number in products_missing_from_postgresql:
    entries = xml_tree.xpath("//entry[@id = '%s']" % product_number)
    if entries:
        print('FOUND: ' + product_number)
    else:
        print('NOT FOUND: ' + product_number)
```

If your `product_number` can contain single quotes, the above will break. It's generally preferable to use a placeholder in the XPath and pass the actual value separately:

```
    entries = xml_tree.xpath("//entry[@id = $value]", value=product_number)
```

Comment: I'd avoid string formatting here and use a variable parameter... eg: `xml_tree.xpath('//entry[@id = $value]', value=product_number)`

Comment: @JonClements I didn't know that lxml supported XPath parameters. Nice!

Comment: You also don't need to check the length of the result... just `if entries:` will do. Or alternatively, modify the xpath to be `xlm_tree.xpath('boolean(//entry[@id=$value])', value=product_number)`

Comment: You're right, that's an antipattern, answer updated. I'd not convert to boolean though, because typically one wants to do something with the found node.

Comment: Huh? Did you expect you could simply copy my code and it runs? Your question did not have enough details for that. You should read it, understand what it does, and write something that follows the same idea and fits your data.